how to run google_news.country from GNews?
I have been using the Python Gnews package to access news about AI. I would like these news to be only from media of a specific country (Chile). However, I am not getting the google_news.country function that in this package should select only news from a specific country. Instead, it gives me news from many different countries.
This is the code I have:
from gnews import GNews
import datetime

noticias = []
for mes in range(1,3):
    start = datetime.date(2019, mes, 1)
    end = datetime.date(2019, mes, 5) 
    country = 'Chile'
    google_news = GNews(language='es', start_date=start, end_date=end, country = country)
    rsp = google_news.get_news("IA|Inteligencia Artificial")
    if rsp is [None]:
        pass
    else:
        noticias.append(rsp) 

would appreciate advice

have you tried the country code ( CL) instead ?

Yes, it doesn't work either

are all the results in the correct language (es)?

Yes, all are in spanish and no other language. However, some  news are from mexico (.mx), spain (.sp), etc...many from a .com journal, and a few are chilean (.cl)

I think that's how google news works, it displays regional results. Do you want only results from sites with domain .cl ??

yes, I would like onlye results from Chile.
top news shows news only from Chile
I don't think google news google_new.country shows regional news because Spain is far away from Chile. Also, the function indicates that the news is country news.

I'm pretty sure you get results from global outlets (in spanish) even if you set region to chile in the google news web app, if you want to get results from specific domain just add site:.cl to your query.
